# Export OLE-object from Excel by c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel-file with script: `getPhotoSheet().OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=strPath, DisplayAsIcon:=False).Top`, which saves a picture to a file.
I need export this file to a folder (I am using c#-app with "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel").
I tried do this in two ways:

1. Save file as html-page.
2. Get object by shapes and copy it to a chart. Save the chart to the folder.
   But it didn't work, I only get this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWfuD.jpg).

So how can I export picture from excel?

Comment: OLE is quite dead, it has been for over 10 years.  Support for it was never added to .NET so nothing useful you can do in C#.  Office apps are the last of the Mohicans, too hard to remove it perhaps.  You just won't have any other program that can still deal with an embedded object, a thumbnail is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when i tried "activate" this object(its was "package" ole-object or  [OLE Compound File](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/OLE_Compound_File)), it had copy in "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp";

And i copied files from excel like that:

```
foreach (OLEObject obj in _WorkSheetExcel.OLEObjects())
{
      Hashtable hs = new Hashtable();
      DirectoryInfo direct = new DirectoryInfo(tempdir);
      foreach (FileInfo file in direct.GetFiles())
      {
          hs.Add(file.Name, null);//get all file names in tempdir
      }
      obj.Activate();//activate oleobject
      foreach (FileInfo file in direct.GetFiles())
      {
          if (!hs.ContainsKey(file.Name) && !file.Extension.ToLower().Contains("tmp"))//find new activated file 
          {
               FileInfo picture = file.CopyTo(pathpicture + picturename  + file.Extension); //copy picture to folder with original extension
               break;
          }
      }
}
```